# How to not to listen on port 3000 on expressjs?

Tags: express, port, listen

I tried to use app.listen(5050), but after running it, it will listen on both 5050 and 3000 ports. How should I make it to listen only on a specific port?

This is the result on `lsof`
[image]
I dont know what is the meaning of that `hbci` and `mmcc` at the end.

Actually the code I was running is from sample on gundb.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const Gun = require('gun');

const port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT ||
    process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT ||
    process.env.PORT ||
    process.argv[2] ||
    8080;

var app = express();
app.use(Gun.serve);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// const server = app.listen(port);
const server = app.listen(5050);
Gun({
    localStore: false,
    web: server
});

console.log('Server started on port ' + port + ' with /gun');

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

got it fix using `node app.js` instead of `node ./bin/www` on the start script on the package.json.

maybe this line of code on `./bin/wwww` that is causing it.

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

but I don't want to touch it for now.